# Offset lseek for reading /proc/pid/mem

Tags: c, linux

I 'm trying to read the proc/pid/mem stack of a process (i use ptrace to trace it)

1)I read /proc/pid/maps and I save the begining and the end of the stack in

```
unsigned int start_stack, end_stack;
```

2)I use lseek and read to read the memory at the stack adress

I'have a problem when i try to read :

```
  int mem_file = open (mem_file_name, O_RDONLY);
  if(mem_file==-1)perror("open file mem_file failed");

  printf("start_stack = %x, end_stack = %x \n", 
     start_stack, end_stack);

  /*I think the problem is here, but i'm not sure*/
  if(lseek(mem_file, start_stack, 
       SEEK_SET)==-1)perror("lseek failed");

  int buf_size = (int)(end_stack-start_stack);
  buf = calloc(buf_size, sizeof(char));

  if(read(mem_file, buf, size_buf) == -1 )perror("read failed");
  printf("buf=");
  for(i=0; i<size_buf; i+=2)
      printf("%02x",buf[i]);
```

And the output is :

```
start stack = bffde000, end stack = bffff000 
buf = 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Maybe am I wrong with the offset of lseek ? In this example, the offset is (unsigned int)bffde00, the start of the stack.

Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: 1. You don't have to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.  2. `sizeof(char)` is `1`. 3. Are you expecting `buf` to contain a string?

Comment: @Carl Norum : Yes i'm expecting buf contain a char

Comment: .. and does it?  What happens when you log the bytes (like with a loop & `%02x`) rather than as a string?

Comment: You are right, buf contain only 0... output :buf = 0000000000000000, i dont understand, the stack is not empty

Answer (score 4):

`int` or `unsigned int` are not large enough to describe a memory address on 64-bit Linux architectures (because they're all LP64, not ILP64).

Use `unsigned long` instead. It is large enough to hold any memory address on all Linux architectures.

On most architectures in Linux, the stack grows *down*. This means that it is *expected* that the lowest addresses of the stack are zero. The "oldest" values in the stack are at the highest addresses.

`unistd.h` low-level I/O is allowed to return short reads. This means that you cannot just call `read()`, check that the result is not -1, and assume it read all you asked for. It returns the number of chars it did read, and that may well be less than you asked for. All of the common low-level I/O functions may also return -1 with `errno == EINTR` in case a signal was delivered (for example, when stopping or continuing the program).

For example, to open a file or pseudo-file read-only:

```
do {
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
} while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
if (fd == -1)
    /* Cannot open, see strerror(errno) */
```

To close a file descriptor,

```
do {
    result = close(fd);
} while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
if (result == -1)
    /* Delayed write error, or other I/O error,
       see strerror(errno) */
```

To read some data from a specific offset, `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` and use `pread()`:

```
/* Read length chars into buffer starting at offset
 * from descriptor fd. Returns 0 if success,
 * errno error code otherwise; ENOSPC if a premature
 * end of input occurs. */
int read_from(const int fd, const off_t offset,
              void *const buffer, size_t const length)
{
    char   *const ptr = buffer;
    size_t  have = 0;
    ssize_t n;

    while (have < length) {

        n = pread(fd, ptr + have, length - have, offset + (off_t)have);
        if (n > (ssize_t)0)
            have += n;

        else
        if (n == (ssize_t)0)
            return errno = ENOSPC; /* Premature end of input */

        else
        if (n != (ssize_t)-1)
            return errno = EIO; /* Kernel bug catcher */

        else
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While you don't *have to* use `pread()`, the above `read_from()` function works even if multiple threads were to read from the same file simultaneously; that's why POSIX.1-2001 added support for `pread()` and `pwrite()`.

(If you want to make sure `off_t` is 64-bit, `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64`. On all 64-bit Linux systems it already is, so for this particular program it's not required.)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i've tried your code, and i have errno != EINTR. I'have try to read /proc/pid/mem on an other part of the memory (like /lib/i386-linux...) and it works. I really do not understand why. Thanx for your help

Comment: @user2608201: Not all maps are readable; if there is no `r` in the second field in the `/proc/PID/maps` pseudofile, then you cannot read that part of the process memory via the `/proc/PID/mem` pseudofile either. The standard libraries do use such mappings, so it is quite expected and normal that you cannot read all maps from a process, even if you have all the requisite privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading memory, and printf will stop at the first null byte it finds (0).  What if there's a 0 there?  You stop, and get 0.

Comment: After some tests, i'm now sure buf is empty, the read(mem_file, buf, size_buf) doesnt fill the char *buf. I don't understand why.